# CRC32C SSE vs BOOST

Tags: visual-c++, boost, sse

I am trying to optimize a piece of my code that is running a CRC32 check.

For a test buffer, I did the following:

```
char *buff = new char[1024];
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i)
    buff[i] = i;
```

Currently, I am using boost's crc implementation as follows:

```
boost::crc_optimal<32, 0x1EDC6F41, 0, 0> crc;
crc.process_bytes(buff, 1024);
unsigned int boostCRC = crc();
```

Which means the polynomial "0x1EDC6F41" with an initial value of 0, and a final xor of 0.

Then, I wrote the simplest possible sse4.2 version of the crc32c algorithm:

```
unsigned int sseCRC = 0;
for (char *iter = buff, *end = buff + 1024; iter != end; ++iter)
    sseCRC = _mm_crc32_u8(sseCRC, *iter);
```

The problem is, the final values don't match, even though the polynomial is supposed to be the same. Has anyone has any experience with this? Am I doing something wrong with the sse version?

Comment: This is almost certainly an endianness issue.  I can't be bothered to read through the documentation for the two functions, but I suggest you do that (very carefully!), and check how they determine endianness.

Comment: [What have you tried to debug it yourself?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Since the SSE version is fixed polynomial, the best I could think of doing was flipping the boost polynomial to 0x416FDC1E, as well as doing things like checking the result after the first character processed, where they immediately diverge. My biggest problem is that information on the sse version is extremely sparse, so I was hoping someone might drop by with an answer from personal experience trying to use the sse version to enlighten me before I start digging through the archives.

Comment: Oh, and also reversing the byte order on the answer from the sse version, along with testing xor with 0xFFFFFFFF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Intel® SSE4 Programming Reference](http://softwarecommunity.intel.com/isn/Downloads/Intel%20SSE4%20Programming%20Reference.pdf), the CRC instruction do bit reflection which is off by default in the boost CRC template. Using

```
boost::crc_optimal<32, 0x1EDC6F41, 0, 0, true, true> crc;
```

instead of

```
boost::crc_optimal<32, 0x1EDC6F41, 0, 0> crc;
```

will yield the same checksum as the SSE version.